# Does the compressive strength of materials increase if they are placed under hydrostatic pressure?

Tags: pressure, material-science

Normal measurements of compressive strength work by compressing a sample with an hydraulic press and see when the sample deforms plastically or cracks.

Now if pressure is applied on the surfaces of the sample that aren't in contact with the hydraulic press, will the compressive strength (as seen by the hydraulic press) increase ? If yes, will that increase be exactly the external pressure or lower or higher?

I feel like the compressive strength as seen by the press must be higher because the pressure on the "sides" will prevent the material from going outwards thus deforming or cracking. (Imagine a cylindrical sample is being pressed)

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer on the physical principle behind that or an answer of practical engineering relevance? On the principle, within a linear approximation and e.g. if the material is incompressible, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When an object is subjected to uniaxial compression the lateral dimensions (if not constrained) of the object increase (the Poisson effect). If the lateral dimension were to be somehow constrained, the axial strain would be less for the same applied axial compressive stress.

But to say that increases the "compressive strength" could be misleading, since material properties are usually based on the test used to evaluate them. Restraining the lateral dimension alters the test (uniaxial loading) normally used to evaluate the material's stress-strain properties.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ductile polycrystalline materials, at least, don't really become stronger when placed under hydrostatic stress (i.e., equitrixial compressive stress). You note that pressure would be applied to the sides of a sample being compressed axially, but it's important to recognize that the axial load would increase by the same amount. The [deviatoric stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor), which is the stress associated with plastic deformation, doesn't change. The dislocations are still exposed to the same shear stress that would tend to drive slip and the resulting plastic flow.

As an example, consider the [von Mises yield criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_yield_criterion) for ductile materials and in particular the cylinder visualization. Increasing the hydrostatic component of the load moves the load point parallel to the hydrostatic axis of $\sigma_{xx}=\sigma_{yy}=\sigma_{zz}$ but doesn't move the point closer to the cylinder surface, where yield is predicted to occur.

Now, a nuance is that hydrostatic stress can alter the nature of failure from brittle to ductile. See [Brigman's](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/14786440708637310?casa_token=b_vnisty5ccAAAAA:3wuw_kKGaWQZ7BsHJ8D4wo0GUgYrSZ2LJf5PqIC9uBbBK8N06VgzbRRnkKq2f8FRnbxpg3I4Dtib) seminal [work](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jap/article-abstract/18/2/246/158985/The-Effect-of-Hydrostatic-Pressure-on-the-Fracture) and [Orowon](https://web.archive.org/web/20170812202333id_/http://www.ewp.rpi.edu/hartford/%7Eernesto/Su2014/Korea-PW/Fracture/Readings/Other/Orowan1949-Fracture-Strength-of-Solids.pdf), for example, and the papers citing them. Please clarify if this gets at what you're asking about.

Comment: Yes, it's clear. Thanks !